# Creating a list of rules from a list of integers

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of integers and want to create a list of releation where each integer relates to the next one in the list. (no wrap-around). That is, I want to transform

```
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

to

```
{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4}
```

I tried to replace the expression in the following way:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} //. {x___, a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, y___} :> {x, a -> b, y}
```

but that doesn't give the right result.

Comment: `Rule @@@ Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 1]`

Comment: Teeny modification:  `Rule @@@ Partition[Range[4], 2,1]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

corey979 already gave the standard solution in the comments:

```
Rule @@@ Partition[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2, 1]
```

> `{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4}`

But this is also doable with rules like you tried. I'd do it like this:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} //. {
  {a___, x_Integer, y_Integer, b___} :> {a, x -> y, y, b},
  {rules___Rule, _Integer} :> {rules}
  }
```

> `{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4}`

Answer (score 10):

[`BlockMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html):

```
BlockMap[Apply@Rule, Range@4, 2, 1]

(* {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html), which I'm always looking for a reason to use, and rarely find one:

```
(Most -> Rest)@{1, 2, 3, 4} // Through // Thread

(* {1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4} *)
```